# How to change color of button in material ui using "&:active":?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, frontend

i am using material ui in my project. I want to change the active state of my button. i am using active and hover of material ui, i.e

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    "&:hover": {
      boxShadow: "none",
      background: "red"
    },
    "&:active": {
      boxShadow: "none",
      background: "black"
    }
  }
}));
```

but hover is working, but not active.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zv9vt?file=/demo.js

Comment: Please set up a demo where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

`hover` style is applied when you are hovering the button.

`active` style is applied when you are clicking the button, and before you release the mouse button. When you start clicking the button, you change from the `hover` state to `active` state.

In your code, `hover` and `active` are the same, so you see the same style between the transition. Try changing `active` state to something different:

```js
button: {
  "&:hover": {
    boxShadow: "none",
    background: "red"
  },
  "&:active": {
    boxShadow: "none",
    background: "yellow"
  }
}
```

Comment: @PriyankDeepSingh you may want to hold the mouse button for a while before you see the active style

Comment: but when release... it get lost

Comment: @PriyankDeepSingh Yes, it works as intended. See [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/) article.

Comment: need to change color of button using active?? cant it be chabge

Answer (score 0):

```
button: (active) => {
  return {
   "&:hover": {
     boxShadow: "none",
     background: "red"
   },
   boxShadow: active ? "none" : undefined,// Use your preferer color instead of undefined.
   backgroundColor: active ? "yellow" : undefined, //Use your preferer color instead of undefined.
 };
}
```

In the proposed solution, you have to use a function that takes an **active** parameter. If **active** is **true**, it applies the styles for the button's hover state (no box shadow and a red background), and it also sets the **boxShadow** to "none" and **backgroundColor** to **"yellow"** specifically for the **active** state. If **active** is **false**, it leaves **boxShadow** and **backgroundColor** as undefined, effectively resetting them to their default values.

The key difference between the two approaches is that the your code directly applies styles to the **active** selector, while the prop-based solution conditionally sets the **boxShadow** and **backgroundColor** properties based on the **active** parameter, allowing you to control the **active** state styles dynamically. The prop-based solution is more flexible and can be used to change the **active** state styles programmatically by passing the active parameter when rendering the button. You can see sample of custom button.

```
<CustomButton active=true/>
```